# Convert a string number with comma to a culture specific double number

Tags: c#

```
NumberFormatInfo numberInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
double result = Convert.ToDouble("2,75", numberInfo); 

result = 2.75
```

My current UI/culture is "de-DE".

Why don't i get 2,75 ?

Comment: This is correct isn't it? de uses comma as the radix point, so 2,75 = 2.75?  If you're asking why isn't result 'displayed' as 2.75 that depends on the code you use to display it, not to parse it.

Comment: How do you know `result` is 2.75?! It is a double and a double doesn't save any culture info, it is a simple number. It rather depends on how you output `result`. Or do I not understand your question right?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `2.75`. It's only different ways of displaying the number.

The `double` value contains no information about formatting. It's neither `2.75` nor `2,75`, it's just a numeric value.

If you display the number using a culture that uses a comma as decimal separator, you will get what you expect, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1053)));
```

Output:

```
2,75
```

Comment: I do not get 2,75 ALTHOUGH my culture uses comma as decimal separator with your CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. I have to use this:  result.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) is "2,75" for "de-DE".

Comment: @Elisa: Right, you expected a comma, not period. I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are not getting a `string` result, but a `double`. How you then *display* that double later is not influenced by your code above.

If you want to see "2,75" on your screen, you need to format the double as a string, adding numberInfo.

Comment: "...format the double as a string..." not format the string as a double? sounds twisted... My numberInfo has: numberInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = "," set, so why do I get then a point?

Comment: Because you are not getting a string result, but a double. How you then display that double later is not influenced by your code above. You get a point when you *display* your `result`, which is a `double` -- a number variable, hence it contains no formatting information. Once you display it and you want to display it a certain way, you must tell .NET which format to use. When giving `result` its contents, since it is a number and not a string, format doesn't matter.

Comment: I do not understand you. I do not want to display the value - as my first/priority task - I want to Convert the "2,75" to a double value of 2,75. Ok if double knows NO format how can I then "format" the double value of 2.75 as 2,75 to save it in the database ?

Comment: Are you saving it in your database as a number or as a string?

Comment: If it's a number in .NET, and it's a number in SQL, then why would you need to convert it to a string?

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get 2,75:-

```
  string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"), "{0:0.0}", 2.75);
```

or you can also try this:-

```
  NumberFormatInfo n= new NumberFormatInfo();
  n.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
  n.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";

  double d= 2.75;
  string s= d.ToString(n); //2,75
```